# Set Table at Top over the whole page

Tags: tables, floats

I want to place a table at the top of a page and over the whole width of this page.
My appraoch looks as follows:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
      Language    &     mBERT-Uncased    & mBERT-cased & DistilBERT-cased & MuRIL\\
          &     F1-Macro | F1-Micro   & F1-Macro | F1-Micro & F1-Macro | F1-Micro & F1-Macro | F1-Micro\\          
   \hline
        Hindi & 763 | 123& 1 & & \\
        Tamil & 36 &1 & &\\
        Malayalam & 486 & 1 & &\\
        Bengali & 120 & 1 & &   \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption[Distribution of sentiment in annotated subset]{Distribution of sentiment in annotated subset}
  \label{tab:distribution}
\end{table}
```

However the table looks like this in the PDF:
[image]

However this doens't work. Does anyone know how to display this table and how to not put it over text?
Thnak you!

Comment: Use table* and please always provide full examples that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: you will also need to format your column headings to be not so wide so it fits on the page, also do not use `|` to get  `—` in most font encodings it will give you `|`

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.